# npm not showing in VS2017

Tags: npm, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017, when I right click on Dependencies in the solution, I see `Manage NuGet Packages` but where is npm? Shouldn't there be a visual manager for npm like I use with NuGet all the time?

Answer (score 10):

here you go.

1. On your project do a  right click
2. Select Add New Item
3. Select the NPM Configuration File, this will add a Package.json to your project, it will look like this:

```html
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {

  }
}
```

4. then you can type your dependencies like so:

```html
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-bootlint": "0.8.1"

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [Package Installer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.PackageInstaller)
Is nothing official but its something